# Automated Custom install of different distributions

Tags: linux, software-installation, live-usb, distributions

I spend A LOT of my time setting up linux servers/workstations/mining farms etc. and I need some way to store and automate the process for each of my varying systems as it gets so frustrating.

I have a bunch of bash scripts that handles things but it gets extremely messy when dealing with different distros, package managers, hardware etc.

Is there any software where I could explain the specification in a file. for example `debian.spec` which contains something that resembles:

```
{
    "image": "debian.iso",
    "hostname": "example",

    "packages": [
        "git",
        "gcc",
        "python",
        "oh-my-zsh"
        "zsh"
    ],

    "dotfiles": "git@github.com:example/dotfiles",

    "postinstall": "/path/to/script.sh",
    "autostart": "/path/to/another-script.sh"
}
```

Which produce either an iso to install or live usb.

I need to be able to do this with atleast arch and debian.

Comment: Look into Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use something like Ansible to configure each system after it's been installed as a bare-bones host available on the network. There is no software available, to my knowledge, that will let you create a custom installation ISO or instruction file that will work across distributions. Debian does have a preseed file specification available, but learning that is a skill unique to Debian and will not transfer to Arch.